# Populating angular material tree from HttpClient results in TypeError

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-httpclient

I am trying to set up an angular component based on the Angular Material Tree that gets its data from an http GET request. However, I keep running into this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
    at FlatTreeControl.getDescendants (tree.js:93)
```

To keep things simple, I started with the example *Tree with Checkboxes* from https://material.angular.io/components/tree/examples. Then, I (removed the "add new item" option and) replaced the data source with a very simple Http Client:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export interface Odata {
  '@GrcOdataService.context': string;
  value: object[];
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GrcOdataService {

  private _host : string = 'http://localhost:8080/grcodata/';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  public get(entitySet: string){
    return this.httpClient.get<Odata>(this._host + entitySet);
  }
}
```

The Observable is subscribed to in the constructor:

```
constructor(private _odata:GrcOdataService, private _database:ChecklistDatabase) {
    this.treeFlattener = new MatTreeFlattener(
      this.transformer,
      this.getLevel,
      this.isExpandable,
      this.getChildren);

    this.treeControl = new FlatTreeControl(this.getLevel, this.isExpandable);
    this.dataSource = new MatTreeFlatDataSource(this.treeControl, this.treeFlattener);
    
    // _database.dataChange.subscribe(data => {
    //   console.log(data)
    //   this.dataSource.data = data;
    // })

    _odata.get('AMIs').subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      console.log(this.buildManagementStructure(data));
      this.dataSource.data = this.buildManagementStructure(data);
    });
  }
```

The buildManagementStructure function transforms the odata values to a tree (the levels specify the path):

```
private buildManagementStructure(data: Odata): OrgNode[] {
    var mgmntStructure = new Array<OrgNode>();
    var group = new OrgNode();
    group.name = 'Management Structure';
    group.children = new Array<OrgNode>();
    mgmntStructure.push(group);

    data.value.forEach(element => {
      var keys = ['Level_1', 'Level_2', 'Level_3', 'Level_4', 'Level_5'];

      var path = new Array<string>();
      keys.forEach(key => {
        if (element[key]) path.push(element[key]);
      });

      var node = group;

      path.forEach(segment => {
        var segmentNode = node.children.find(child => child.name === segment);
        if (!segmentNode) {
          segmentNode = new OrgNode();
          segmentNode.name = segment;
          segmentNode.children = new Array<OrgNode>();
          node.children.push(segmentNode);
        }
        node = segmentNode;
      });

      var leaf = new OrgNode();
      leaf.name = element['Unique_ID'] + ' ' + element['Company_Name']
      node.children.push(leaf);
      node = group;
    });
    return mgmntStructure;
  }
```

The resulting tree looks fine to me, however, my browser only shows the top node and gives me the error message shown above. Suprisingly, when I uncomment the following four lines, the code works.

```
    // _database.dataChange.subscribe(data => {
    //   console.log(data)
    //   this.dataSource.data = data;
    // })
```

Apparently, first loading the example data and then overwriting it solves the problem. Therefore, I guess that the problem has something to do with the asynchronous execution of code. But frankly speaking, I do not have a clue what I am doing wrong (I am a beginner). Do you have suggestions what I should do?

Thank you in advance.

Fabian

Answer (score 2):

I now replaced the sample data with an empty array and the problem is gone as well:

```
    this.dataSource.data = [];
```

This fixed the problem - hopefully. It still puzzles me, though.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue: 'ERROR TypeError: this.dataNodes is undefined' and i solved my error with this line: this.dataSource.data = [];